# Passing props to contentComponent in DrawerNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

native app with react-navigation. I have my navigation working but when i add contentComponent from CustomNavigationDrawer.js file i get an error:

[image]
[image]

If i paste the code from CustomNavigationDrawer.js directly in my navigation.js it works but i want the component in a different file so i can keep it seperated.

I tried searching for the problem and it gave me the following result:

**Structure:**

```
├── screens
│   ├── LoginScreen.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── MainScreen.js
│   └── etc...
├── navigation
│   ├── Navigation.js
├── component
│   ├── CustomNavigationDrawer.js
│   ├── index.js
```

**Index.js:**

```
export { CustomDrawerNavigator } from './CustomDrawerNavigator';
export { CustomHeader } from "./CustomHeader";
```

**CustomDrawerNavigator.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { DrawerItems } from "react-navigation";

export const CustomDrawerNavigator = (props) => (
  <View style={[styles.container]}>
    <DrawerItems
      activeBackgroundColor={"black"}
      activeTintColor={"white"}
      iconContainerStyle={styles.icons}
      {...props}
    />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },

  icons: {
    width: 30
  }
});
```

**Navigation.js:**

```
import CustomDrawerNavigator from "../component";
...

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Ionicons name="md-home" style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
        drawerLabel: "Main"
      },
      screen: MainScreen
    },

    Login: {
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Ionicons name="md-settings" style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
        drawerLabel: "Login"
      },
      screen: LoginScreen
    },

    Profile: {
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Ionicons name="ios-person" style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
        drawerLabel: "Profile"
      },
      screen: ProfileScreen
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <CustomDrawerNavigator {...props} />
  }
);

...
```

Can anyone help me to display the contentCompenent from a different file?

Comment: How are you to get props in contentComponent.? I am not getting that in suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import CustomDrawerNavigator from "../component";
```

The above line expects a `default export` for your component ... but nothing found

Grab the named export through this:

```
import { CustomDrawerNavigator } from "../component";
```

Comment: This solved my issue. I knew it was something small but i could not see it at the moment. Thanks very much !

Comment: Glad it helps! ... Happy coding!

Comment: thnks helped me alot guys

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because contentComponent expects a class component, instead of using react-navigation, use react-navigation-drawer to import createDrawerNavigaor and DrawerNavigatorItems (use this instead of DrawerItems)

```js
import { createDrawerNavigator,DrawerNavigatorItems } from "react-navigation-drawer";
```